# Can't compile on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8

Tags: compiling, gcc

I installed build-essential in Ubuntu 14.04 and created a test file helloworld.c with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ printf("Hello world\n"); return 0; }
```

The output of `gcc -o hello helloworld.c` is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Are there any suggestions for what I've done wrongly?

Comment: This question is not off-topic, it's about compilation and doesn't involve programming at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  There was an old, corrupt installation of gcc-4.8, which doesn't get replaced when build-essential is installed.  I used

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc-4.8
sudo apt-get remove --purge
sudo apt-get auto-remove
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now the test runs fine.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgcc-4.8-dev` is enough, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*My two cents:*

The file with the name `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a` is part of the package `libgcc-4.8-dev`

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgcc-4.8-dev
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like that was it